# Ĉu ekzistas etimologia vortaro de Esperanto?

Tags: etymology, websites, dictionaries

Lernante Esperanto, mi ofte povas memori Esperantajn vortojn, afiksojn kaj radikojn pli bone, se mi scias ilia(j)n origino(j)n. **Ĉu ekzistas etimologia vortaro de Esperanto?** Se jes, ĉu ekzistas *reta* etimologia vortaro de Esperanto?

Comment: Simila demando ĉe reddit: [Is there a way to find out Esperanto word etymology?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/comments/3b4hwn/is_there_a_way_to_find_out_esperanto_word/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas du bonaj libroformaj etimologiaj vortaroj de Esperanto:

1. Plej fidinda kaj scienca estas la kvinvoluma [Etimologia Vortaro de
   Esperanto](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=3684) de Ebbe Vilborg, aperinta inter 1989 kaj 2001. Ĝi
   enhavas ampleksajn diskutojn de la vortprovizo (inkl. morfologiajn
   elementojn) de la [Universala Vortaro](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/universala_vortaro.html) kaj la 8 ĝistiamaj
   Oficialaj Aldonoj.
2. La [Konciza Etimologia Vortaro](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=6912) de André Cherpillod havas, se
   entute, nur tre mallongajn diskutojn, sed ampleksas pli da vortoj ol
   Vilborg kaj estas kompakta (unu volumo je permesebla prezo).

Mi nur fluglegis iom en la etimologia vortaro de Rajki. Ĝi estas vortlisto sen diskuto, tiel ĝi taŭgas por la klaraj okazoj, sed ne por la diskutindaj.

Answer (score 2):

Ekzistas la [Etimologia Vortaro de Andras Rajki](https://archive.org/details/EsperantoEtymologicalDictionary). Ĝi estas libere elŝutebla.

Comment: A MS Word document? o_O

Comment: But it's CC0-licensed, so we can make useful stuff from it. Maybe convert it to JSON or something.

Comment: Ho, [en.wikipedia avertas pri ĝi](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Esperanto_etymology&oldid=885130179#External_links): "Note: This dictionary should be used with caution. For example, _amelo_ (starch) is given as a rare example of a Greek word that does not occur in Latin. However, it is not only a Latin derivation (from _amyl-um_), but more directly derives from German _amel-_."

Comment: Do, verŝajne indas kontakti lin kaj plibonigi ĝin, ĉu?

Answer (score 1):

Aldone al la aliaj respondoj, [ĉi tiu](http://www.romaniczo.com/esperanto/vortaroj/etimologio.html) vortaro estas havebla rete.